# SQL Server : sum and multiplies on 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

I need help to SUM and MULTIPLIES on join 2 tables:

**tb1**

[image: Tabel 1]

**tb2**

[image: Tabel 2]

In `tb1`, I need to **sum** `QTY` and **multiples** `SKU` with `PRICE` without repeating same `SKU` (`21135208`, `21035621`):

Current query:

```
SELECT
    tb1.DOC_NO,
    CAST(SUM(tb2.QTY) AS FLOAT) AS QTY_TOTAL,
    ROUND(CAST(SUM(tb2.QTY * tb2.PRICE) AS FLOAT), 2) AS PRICE_TOTAL,
    tb1.DATE,
    tb1.STATUS_A,
    tb2.STATUS_B 
FROM
    tb1
INNER JOIN 
    tb2 ON tb1.DOC_NO = tb2.DOC_NO
WHERE
    tb1.STATUS_B = '0'
GROUP BY
    tb1.DOC_NO, tb1.DATE,
    tb1.STATUS_A, tb1.STATUS_B 
ORDER BY
    COH.DOC_NO_REQ_TO_ULI DESC
```

My result is:

[image]

Expected result is:

[image]

Comment: why are there duplicates in `tbl1` in the first place ? and what does column `CM` indicates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you could filter out duplicates by using a subquery like `SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM tb1`, while leaving the rest of the query untouched:

```
SELECT
    tb0.DOC_NO,
    CAST ( SUM ( tb2.QTY ) AS FLOAT ) AS QTY_TOTAL,
    ROUND( CAST ( SUM ( tb2.QTY * tb2.PRICE ) AS FLOAT ), 2) AS PRICE_TOTAL,
    tb0.DATE,
    tb2.STATUS_A,
    tb2.STATUS_B 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT DOC_NO, CM, SKU, PRICE, QTY, DATE FROM tb1) AS tb0
    INNER JOIN tb2 ON tb0.DOC_NO = tb2.DOC_NO
WHERE
    tb2.STATUS_B = '0'
GROUP BY
    tb0.DOC_NO,
    tb0.DATE,
    tb2.STATUS_A,
    tb2.STATUS_B 
ORDER BY
    COH.DOC_NO_REQ_TO_ULI DESC
```

NB: there are some issues with the table aliases in your query:

- columns `STATUS_A` or `STATUS_B` should be prefixed `tb2`, not `tb1` (I fixed that)
- alias `COH` which is being used in the `ORDER BY` clause is not declared anywhere in the query (that's a syntax error)

Comment: thank for your information and help, forgot to edit alias `coh`